# Need advice on the usage of .indexOf();

Tags: java

I have some code:

```
firstWord = sentance.substring (0, sentance.indexOf(' '));
secondWord = sentance.substring(sentance.indexOf(' ') + 1);
```

the code is used for selecting the first word out of a string without the use of arrays.
However I am wondering if I can further fool-proof my code by implementing a safeguard so that if the user inputs two spaces, the code will take the group of white space and count it as one unit.

Is this possible without the use of arrays, or loops?

For example the user would input this:
"Hello *2spaces*  there"
the user accidentally inputted two spaces in the beginning which will mess the program up when it tries to take the second word i think.

Comment: If arrays and loops are taboo (why?), how about regular expressions?

Comment: why dont you want to user array? You can use it efficiently

Comment: regular expressions are fine. This is an assignment and the prof doesn't want us to use stuff we "haven't" learnt yet.

Comment: who learns regular expressions before loops and arrays?

Answer (score 4):

remove multiple space with single space as :

```
String str="Hello                  world this         is   string";
str=str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
.......// do whatever you want
```

Comment: I like this! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not take the first word out of string only if the first character of the string is a space, or before the first space is not a word, or there is no space, for example `" hello" -> "", "!@#! blah" -> "!@#!", "asdasd" -> ""`

Comment: Yeah i forgot to mention that the sentence will only ever contain two words.

Answer (score 0):

`y.indexOf(x)` returns the index of the first occurrence of `x` in `y`.

Your solution is mostly foolproof, but it will fail to get the first word if there are spaces before it, or there is no whitespace in the specified string, because `indexOf` would return `-1`.

You should call the `.trim()` method on the string object you want to get the first word of, it will remove the whitespace around the string, and then add a single space character at the end of the string.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I forgot about people adding accidental spaces on there.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "Hello I'm your String";
String[] splited = str.split("\\s+");
```

You can use arrays they are not that bad.

Comment: I am restricted as this is an assignment not including the use of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* must avoid using an array, you could use `sentance.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");` first to collapse all sequences of consecutive whitespace into singleton spaces.

(Similarly, you would want to `trim()` leading and trailing whitespace as well.)

Comment: Yeah this is what I am going to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove trailing and leading whitespace use `.trim()`

```
str = str.trim()
```